# How to send HTTP requests using wifi of Arduino Primo board?

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, esp8266

I have bought an Arduino Primo board. I have configured it to connect to my wifi router and changed it to STA mode. Now, how do I program it to send HTTP requests to a server? Which library file I should use? Any tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

With Arduino Primo use the WiFi Link library. Look at WiFi Link Examples in IDE menu.

[Arduino org web archive pages](https://web.archive.org/web/20170711112326/http://www.arduino.org/products/boards/arduino-primo)